# What is smartest way to parse string? (ios)

Tags: ios, string, parsing

I got coming string from request like:

```
 1 Ghanaian Cedi = 155.15541 Zimbabwe dollar
```

I want to have 155.15541 in double. How can I do what?

I hear about predicate, can it help here?

Comment: try [NSScanner](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: ok, I will take it, and can I firstly delete first character and then search for double in remained string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to parse this string into components separated by the blank spaces use

```
NSArray *components = [string componentSeparatedBy:@" "];
```

to get an NSArray in which each index contains each group of characters.  In this particular case, your string would return an array containing:

```
[@"1", @"Ghanaian", @"Cedi", @"=", @"155.15541", @"Zimbabwe", @"dollar"]
```

If the desired double is always at index 4, you can convert the corresponding string to a double using

```
double result = [[components objectAtIndex:4] doubleValue];
```

If the double isn't always at the same index, maybe you could use a regex to identify the double(s).